"1: This: not found" at any yarn command | NodeJS
I've been trying to setup an environment for a project I was working on windows using WSL. It uses yarn for package management. After setting up everything and installing node, any command with yarn simply does not run, returning with:
/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: 1: This: not found
According to this solution, deleting the 'node' file from the directory (which is just plain text) fixes it, however upon deleting that file, I get this error:
/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/npm/node: 12: exec: /mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: not found
Any commands that involve node do not work because of this.
